# How to pass a generic class as ColumnType in ActiveRecord?

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate, activerecord

I have a generic class that implement IUserType.
I want to assign the type to a proprty attribute, so ar can cast string to enum by it.

If i use it like this:

```
[Property("MY_DB_NAME", ColumnType = "B.NewClass,B")]
```

And create the class :
 public class NewClass : MyGeneicClass<EnumName>{}

it work well.

However, i want pass the generic class as a string to the ColumnType like this:

```
[Property("MY_DB_NAME", ColumnType = "B.MyGeneicClass<EnumName>,B")]
```

is throw expetion that nhibenate dont know the sign '<'.

Anybody know how i can pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to check this Ayende blog post about generics mapping: [NHibernate and Generic Entities](http://ayende.com/blog/2951/nhibernate-and-generic-entities)

An example mapping:

```
<class name="ContactInformation`1[System.String]" ...
```

So, you can try:

```
[Property("MY_DB_NAME", ColumnType = "MyGeneicClass`1[EnumName]")]
```

Comment: I try it, it throw this error:
Could not determine type for: MyGeneicClass`1[EnumName]
for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(DBColumnName)

Comment: Of course, such a generic-type must be mapped. As shown in the link. In general, I would suggest do not use generics for mapping. Avoid that if possible, because you will have more problems then benefits. I rather create the derived types (no generics) and map / reference these